# Couldn't connect to host port: smtp.gmail.com 22. Even though i have port 465 set on application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jakarta-mail

My application.properties:

```
#E-mail properties Gmail
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=derp@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=DERP
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
```

My EmailSender method(added Properties to this part to see if it would work, it didn't):

```
public void sendEmail(String title, String message, String email) {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("spring.mail.port","465");
        SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
        msg.setTo(email);

        msg.setSubject(title);
        msg.setText(message);
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Erro ao enviar o email para:" + email);
        }
        javaMailSender.send(msg);

    }
```

I thought my application wasn't accessing the application.properties for some reason, but since I'm getting values from database I'm pretty sure it's accessible. All search I've done ends up in people using the wrong port or stuff like that. The sender is in a different project i have the MailSenderCore and the one that does other logics so i thought it was because of that and tried adding an application.properties to both projects just to test it out but still the same error.

this is my log:

```
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out). Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:448) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:323) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:312) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sippulse.email.core.SipPulseEmailServiceImpl.sendEmail(SipPulseEmailServiceImpl.java:89) ~[SipPulseEmailCore-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sippulse.email.lowcredit.SipPulseEmailLowCredit.SipPulseEmailLowCreditApplication.applicationRunner(SipPulseEmailLowCreditApplication.java:50) [classes/:na]
    at com.sippulse.email.lowcredit.SipPulseEmailLowCredit.SipPulseEmailLowCreditApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6db9b225.CGLIB$applicationRunner$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sippulse.email.lowcredit.SipPulseEmailLowCredit.SipPulseEmailLowCreditApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6db9b225$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f2946bba.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sippulse.email.lowcredit.SipPulseEmailLowCredit.SipPulseEmailLowCreditApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6db9b225.applicationRunner(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 25; timeout -1
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:722) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:437) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:335) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:214) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2160) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Use 587 as the port number.

Comment: Tried it out to the same effect, the weird part is that my log comes out as not being able to connect to port 25.

Comment: Do you add `spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true` to the `application.properties` too?
And remove `props.put("spring.mail.port","465");` from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [JavaMail FAQ connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).  Most likely you have a firewall or antivirus preventing you from connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Change mail port number from 465 to 587 and enable `TLS`.

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=derp@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=DERP
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Comment: As i pointed out  on the Alien answer did those modifications to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

There are few points to work on.

1. Remove email's password from the question so that someone cannot mis use of it.
2. Enable less secure apps on Gmail [here](https://myaccount.google.com/security)
3. There is one more port 587 which you can use for SMTP.
4. Enable TLS refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email)

Comment: Ok after a lot more testing, same results, i have done all those steps to no avail.Oh the email and password are just there to show, they are not actually the ones I'm using.